# MySQL: Change in column value between oldest and newest date in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

Following table in MySQL:

```
id| value | date
```

There are multiple records for the same ID for different dates, i want for each **"id"** to calculate the difference in the column **"value"** between the records with oldest and newest **"date"** in my table.

In other words, display something like (remember value is the column "Value"):

```
id | Most Recent Value - Oldest Value
```

Any help/tips would be more than welcome! So far, I have tried to self-join the table 2 times to take the records for both first and last date using min() & max() but no luck, i am getting NULL as "Value" for min() dates.

```
SELECT t.id, (t2.value - t3.value) AS Difference
FROM table t 

LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT t2.id, t2.value, MAX(t2.date) as TopDate
    FROM table t2
    GROUP BY t2.id) AS LatestValue
ON LatestValue.TopDate = t.date AND LatestValue.id = t.id

LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT t3.id, t3.value, MIN(t3.date) as BotDate
    FROM table t3
    GROUP BY t3.id) AS FirstValue
ON FirstValue.BotDate = t.date AND FirstValue.id = t.id

GROUP BY t.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  select t1.id, t1.`value` - t2.`value` as res from 
      (
          select t.id, `value` from t
          inner join (select id,   max(`date`) dt   from t group by id) mx
          on t.id = mx.id and t.`date` = mx.dt
      )t1
      inner join (
          select t.id, `value` from t
          inner join (select id,   min(`date`) dt   from t group by id) mn
          on t.id = mn.id and t.`date` = mn.dt
      ) t2
  on t1.id = t2.id
```

Side note: try to not use words like `value`,  `date` as column names

Comment: It worked, thanks! Different logic on how the joins are performed. However if i try to order the results by **res** to have the records with biggest variation first, the query seems to crash

Comment: @balalaika - if add at the end `order by res desc` , it doesn't works?

Comment: Nope, query takes too long to execute and DB connection is lost

Comment: @balalaika - Do you have properly indexed your columns? may be missed indexes are reason of bad performance ?

Answer (score 1):

In your inner queries the way group by was used if wrong. IT won't get you the correct value. In your outer queries also you don't need a group by. 
If you want to do it the way you were doing, then the Correct query is:-

```
SELECT t.id, (LatestValue.value - FirstValue.value) AS Difference
FROM table t 
LEFT JOIN 
  (
   SELECT id,value, date as TopDate
   FROM TABLE a
   INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT t2.id, MAX(t2.date) as TopDate
    FROM table t2
    GROUP BY t2.id 
    ) b
   ON a.id=b.id and a.date=b.TopDate
  ) LatestValue

ON LatestValue.TopDate = t.date AND LatestValue.id = t.id

LEFT JOIN 
  (
   SELECT id,value, date as BotDate
   FROM table a
   INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT t3.id,MIN(t3.date) as BotDate
    FROM table t3
    GROUP BY t3.id 
    ) b 
   ON a.id=b.id and a.date=b.BotDate
  ) FirstValue
ON FirstValue.BotDate = t.date AND FirstValue.id = t.id;
```

Let me know if this works or if you have any questions.

Comment: thanks, solution from @Oto accepted but your answer is also correct. I will try to test it later on. Would you suggest a more efficient way for this query to avoid multiple joins?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that scans the table only once.  It uses MySQL variables to work around the lack of window functions.

```
select  id
,       first_val - last_val
from    (
        select  case when id <> @id and @id <> -1 then @id end as id
        ,       case when id <> @id then @first_val end as first_val
        ,       case when id <> @id then @last_val end as last_val
        ,       @first_val := case when id <> @id then `value` else @first_val end
        ,       @last_val := `value`
        ,       @id := id
        from    (
                select  *
                from    (
                        select  *
                        from    YourTable
                        order by
                                id desc
                        ,       date
                        ) sorted
                union all
                select  -1
                ,       null
                ,       null
                ) with_closer
        cross join (select @id := -1, @first_val := 0, @last_val := 0) r
        ) calc
where   id is not null
```

This should perform well, especially with an index on `(id desc, date, value)`.

[Working example at regtester.](http://rextester.com/LMDY14923)